# Don't see simple_fields_for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

```
Job belongs_to :order
Order has_many :jobs

Job accepts_nested_attributes_for :order
```

Form to edit notes doesn't show up. Why?

```
<% order = @job.order %>
<%= simple_form_for @job,
  url: admin_job_path(@job),
  method: :put,
  remote: true do |f| %>
  # (...) fields for @job do show up normally
  # can't see the field below:
    <% f.simple_fields_for order do |form| %>
          <%= form.input(
            :notes,
            input_html:
              {
                value: (order.notes),
                rows: 7,
                class: 'form-control'
              }
            )
          %>
    <% end %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<% end %>
```

Adding some text because "it's mostly code". I hope the answer is clear without too much elaboration, but can always add more datails if you need. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> Form to edit notes doesn't show up. Why?

You are missing `=` here `<% f.simple_fields_for order do |form| %>`. It should be

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for order do |form| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't update the order tho.

```
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(
      :id, (...) #should add it here in the job controller?
    )
  end
```

Comment: In order controller it's permitted

Comment: @Giovani Can you add the `job_params` method in the question?

Comment: @Giovani You should mark my answer as corrected as it answers your question.